# Flexslider height has much amount of spaces on each slide

Tags: css, flexslider

I'm currently working on a page to make the slider height size automatically re-size each time the slider content changes on this [page](http://www.junk2go.co.nz/commercial-waste-removal/).

[image]

I tried to add `min-size: 0;` and `height:0;` on `li` elements and to its child elements however it doesn't seem to work. Both of the styles work usually on flex sliders I worked with.

What did I miss on the styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be your problem here is with max-height

> .flex-viewport

Try adjusting the height values and check,
And also in js add this property `smoothHeight: true,`

Comment: `smoothHeight:true` is a quick fix. Thanks a lot stanze. :)